# Sorting in ruby without using .sort

Tags: ruby

Sort the elements of two sorted arrays **without using .sort method** and put the sorted elements in a new array in RUBY

I have two arrays, like this:

```
a = [1,4,6,9]
b = [2,5,7,8]
```

and my output should be:

```
c = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please add what you have tried and at what point you need specific help. Otherwise it smells a lot like homework.

Answer (score 0):

You cerainly want to make use of the fact that the two arrays to be merged are already sorted. This is one way to do that:

```
def merge_sort(a,b)
  ac, bc = a.dup, b.dup
  (a.size+b.size).times.each_with_object([]) do |_,c|
    c <<
      case [ac.any?, bc.any?]
      when [true,true]  then (ac.first <= bc.first) ? ac.shift : bc.shift
      when [true,false] then ac.shift
      else                   bc.shift
      end
   end
 end

 a = [1,4,6,9]
 b = [2,5,7,8]    

 c = merge_sort a,b 
   #=> [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The first line is to avoid mutating (changing) `a` or `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much but i want to store it in a new array

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I've edited to use the three variable names in your question: `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will help you do what you want.

```
def my_sort_function(a,b)
  n = a.length + b.length
  if a.length < b.length
    min = a.length
  else
    min = b.length
  end
  c=[]

    min.times do |i|
      if a[i] > b[i]
        c << b[i]
        c  << a[i]
      else
        c << a[i]
        c  << b[i]
        end
    end
  if min == a.length

    (c << b[(min)..(b.length-1)]).flatten!

  else
    (c << a[(min)..(a.length-1)]).flatten!

  end

  loop do
    swapped = false

    (n-1).times do |i|
      if c[i] > c[i+1]
        c[i], c[i+1] = c[i+1], c[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end

    break if not swapped
  end
  c
end

a = [1,4,6]
b = [2,5,7,8]

puts a    #=> a:[1,4,6]
puts b    #=> b:[2,5,7,8]

c= my_sort_function(a,b)
puts c    #=> c:[1,2,4,5,6,7,8]
puts "sorting Done!"
```

Comment: But i want to compare the elements of two arrays first and later add them to a new array like

Comment: a = {1,4,6,9}
b = {8,5,2,7}

if a[i] > b[i]
push c[i] = b[i]
push c[i+1] = a[i]

else if b[i] > a[i]
push c[i] = a[i]
push c[i+1] = b[i]

Comment: But in your question you are saying that the two arrays are sorted, you may want to edit the question

Comment: consider my both arrays a & b are sorted arrays

Comment: like a = {1,4,6,9} and b = {2,5,7,8}

Comment: In this case, camparing two arrays and put the result in an another one is the same if we have an array unsorted and we want to sort it from scratch,

Comment: i see what you are searching for iam editing my answer now

Comment: the two arrays has to have the same length or not ?

Comment: they may or may not be of a same length

Comment: ok thanks wait for my edit

Comment: OK, i hope i answred your question now !:)